# How can we use an "array" and "for" loop involving an array of sound clips(mp3's) - non-OOP approach!! [as3]

Tags: actionscript-3

can anybody please tell me how we can use an "array" and "for" loop involving an array of sound clips(mp3's).I tried a similar approach as usually used for movieclips (eg., given below), but for mp3's it does not seem to work...please don't give the OOP approach, since I am a Kindergarten kid as far as as3 is concerned and have no idea about OOP in as3.....thnx in advance

```
var simplify1:Array = new Array(lev3Bar1, lev3Bar2, lev3Bar3,
lev3Bar4, lev3Bar5, lev3Bar6, lev3Bar7, lev3Bar8, lev3Bar9);
for (var i=0; i<simplify1.length ; i++){    

simplify1[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, lev3BarAlphMax)
function lev3BarAlphMax(event:MouseEvent):void{

if (event.target==lev3Bar1){lev3Bar1.alpha = 1;}
if (event.target==lev3Bar2){lev3Bar2.alpha = 1;}
if (event.target==lev3Bar3){lev3Bar3.alpha = 1;}
if (event.target==lev3Bar4){lev3Bar4.alpha = 1;}
if (event.target==lev3Bar5){lev3Bar5.alpha = 1;}
if (event.target==lev3Bar6){lev3Bar6.alpha = 1;}
if (event.target==lev3Bar7){lev3Bar7.alpha = 1;}
if (event.target==lev3Bar8){lev3Bar8.alpha = 1;}
if (event.target==lev3Bar9){lev3Bar9.alpha = 1;}

}
}
```

Comment: This should work, unless you want to click on sound clips... State your problem more clearly, and don't write in caps. Write any error the compiler is giving you.

Comment: Yes i wish to click on sound clips.

Comment: A sound clip is not a graphic object on the screen. It eludes me how you plan to click on one, but in any case, mouse events can only be attached to InteractiveObject object, that is, Sprite and Movieclip.

Comment: You might as well turn that into an answer, Juan.

Comment: I m sorry. i guess my question is not clear. i have 26 alphabets movie clips on the stage. when i click on one, it will pronounce the alphabet (since it is linked to an mp3). so basically, instead of writing a complete event-listener code for each alphabet, i want to shrink the code down by using the array and for loop method.

Comment: So i want to write something like: if (event.target==alphabA){sound1.play();} and put (sound1, sound 2...) in an array. I need to shrink the code because, the App tht i m building contains various levels and the sound clips are used in various areas.